# A question about oracle upgrade from 12.0.0.1 to 12.0.0.2 using dbua

Tags: oracle, upgrade, oracle-12c

I found this [guide](http://www.dbaglobe.com/2014/07/step-by-step-screenshots-upgrading.html) for upgrade.
After the upgrade, can I delete safely the old DB product dir
/var/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0 ?

Comment: Isn't there an official description for the upgrade steps?

Comment: There is neither a version named `12.0.0.1` nor `12.0.0.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but do not simply delete it - deinstall it properly: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LADBI/remove_oracle_sw.htm#LADBI7824

Run `$ORACLE_HOME/deinstall/deinstall` and follow the instructions.

Comment: So i did 1)Install new 12c release 2)ugprade my db with dbua 3)Deinstall after sucessfully upgrade?

Comment: I did this works fine,thanks all for help